# How to do edit and update function in Laravel 8.9?

Tags: php, html, laravel, routes, controller

After submit the registration form, I want to redirect it to the edit/update form but I get the error. Edit/update form is getting the value from database based on the registered form that insert by the user. So, each user can review the form that they entered and update it.

> 404 | Not Found

The edit form is homedit.blade.php. This is the code.

```
   <form method="post" action="{{route(homedit,$hm->id)}}"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
              
                    <label for="fullName"><b>Full Name as per NRIC :</b></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fullName" value="{{$hm['fullName']}}"/>
               
                    <label for="icno"><b>I/C No :</b></label>
                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="icno" pattern="[0-9]{12}" value="{{$hm['icno']}}"/>
                
                    <label for="email"><b>Email :</b></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{Auth::user()->email}}"/>
               
                    <label for="gender"><b>Gender :</b></label>
                     <select name="gender" id="gender" class="form-control" >
                        @foreach ($hm as $home)
                        <option value="{{$hm['id']}}"> {{$hm['gender']}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                        <option value="female"> female</option>
                    </select>
                  </form>
```

This is the code for controller

```
    public function createhome(Request $request)
     {
       return view('home');
     }

public function home(Request $request)
{
  
    $hm = new Register();
    $hm->fullName = $request->input('fullName');
    $hm->icno = $request->input('icno');
    $hm->email = $request->input('email');
    $hm->gender = $request->input('gender');
    $hm->record_id = Auth::user()->id;

    $hm->save();
    return redirect('/homedit')->with('success', 'Your personal details have been saved!');
}  

   public function updatehome(Request $request, $id)
{  
    $hm = Register::find($id);
    $hm->fullName = $request->fullName;
    $hm->icno = $request->icno;
    $hm->email = $request->email;
    $hm->gender = $request->gender;
  
    $hm->save();
    return redirect('/homedit')->with('success', 'Your personal details have been updated!');
}


public function edithome($id){
    $hm = Register::find($id);
    return view('homedit', compact ('hm'));

}
```

This is the code for web.php

```
Route::get('/home', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApplicantController@createhome');
Route::post('/home', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApplicantController@home');

Route::get('/homedit/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApplicantController@edithome');
Route::post('/homedit/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApplicantController@updatehome');
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... you need to be passing something for the `{id}` segment of that route `/homedit/{id}` when making the redirect to that URI

Answer (score 0):

add another input field  below csrf like like name=id and value="{{$hm['id']}}"
because without finding id in view file record can not be update , record found and update on the id

Answer (score 0):

Ok,the mistake here is you have not even set the route name , then how you are using
`action="{{route(homedit,$hm->id)}}"`
the route function takes route name, not uri.So update your route as

```
Route::post('/homedit/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApplicantController@updatehome')->name('homedit');
```

Above all these its good to follow up framework directions as much as possible. For record updates Laravel uses "PUT" request and use implicit binding.

Comment: did you mean like this?
`Route::get('/homedit', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApplicantController@edithome')->name('homedit');
Route::post('/homedit/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApplicantController@updatehome')->name('homedit');`

Comment: every route has a different name. So for GET request u need to name it differently .
`Route::post('/homedit/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApplicantController@updatehome')->name('homedit');`
`Route::get('/homedit', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApplicantController@edithome')->name('anyothername');`